# Create if else for post types in WP_Query 'post__in' values

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, custom-field, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to enable users to select individual posts by custom post type using a new `WP_Query`

```
$posts = new WP_Query( array(
        'post__in'       => selected_posts(),
        'post_type'      => $post_types,
    ) );
```

And using a custom function based on user selection but its not working

```
function selected_posts() {

    $post_in = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'post_in', true );

    $page_in = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'page_in', true );

    $custom_post_type_in = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'custom_post_type_in', true );

    if ( $custom_post_type_in == 'true' ) :

    $show = $custom_post_type_in;

    elseif ( $page_in == 'true' ) :
    $show = $page_in;

    else :
    $show = $post_in;

    endif;

}
```

The value for `post__in` parameter should be shown when a specific post type is selected including post, page and cpt and only posts selected for that post type should be shown using the `'post__in'` parameter.

Comment: Is the array return missing?

Comment: @birgire No i tried adding return $show but not working.

Comment: Try `return array( 123, 321 );` and then expand on that. Most likely your meta is storing string. Check the type/value of all your variables.

Comment: @birgire No i want to return the value for each post id selected from the multi select drop down menu and then add that to the value for ''post__in' in WP_Query